# Need to pass arguments in adcfgclone.pl script

Tags: perl, oracle-database

I just wanted to know is there any way to pass the arguments in perl script (`adcfgclone.pl`) during compilation time (i.e., the values should not be asked during script run time)

Below is an example that i am passing the values after running the script.

Provide the values required for creation of the new APPL_TOP Context file.

```
Target System Hostname (virtual or normal) [proddb] :
Target Instance is RAC (y/n) [n] : n    
Target System Database SID : proddb1    
Target System Base Directory : /d06/oravis    
Target System utl_file_dir Directory List : /usr/tmp    
Number of DATA_TOP's on the Target System [1] : 1    
Target System DATA_TOP Directory 1 [/d01/oravsn12/db/apps_st/data] : /d06/oravis/db/apps_st/data    
Target System RDBMS ORACLE_HOME Directory [/d06/oravis/db/tech_st/10.2.0] : /d06/oravis/db/tech_st/10.2.0    
Do you want to preserve the Display [null] (y/n) ? : n    
Target System Display [sharkap:0.0] :    
Target System Port Pool [0-99] : 34
```

Note: I am entering all the above values during the script run time, so i just pass those all arguments in one file and just run the `adcfgclone.pl` script.

Comment: I am running below one : 
perl /d06/oravis/db/tech_st/10.2.0/appsutil/clone/bin/adcfgclone.pl dbTier /d06/oravis/db/tech_st/10.2.0/appsutil/CLONE3_sharkap.xml \ show progress \

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with [tag:linux-kernel]. Quick googling suggests the tag [tag:oracle-database] as at least roughly correct; but please review and, if possible, add context.

Comment: The tool seems to accept a "context file" with values for it to run with. You could create a simple script which generates such a file with some parameters provided by the user as command-line arguments; is this what you are trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly honest, I don't know if this is exactly what you want. That whole perl compile time/run time thing is a little confusing to me.

You can try autoexpect (included in the expect package). Initially, you have to run your perl app through autoexpect, answering the inputs. But after that, you only need to run the output script generated by autoexpect, which fills in all of the inputs.

### cat expect-test.pl

```
#!/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter your input: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
print "You typed: $input\n";
```

---

```
autoexpect -f expect-test.exp ./expect-test.pl
autoexpect started, file is expect-test.exp
Enter your input: bob 
You typed: bob
autoexpect done, file is expect-test.exp
```

---

```
./expect-test.exp
spawn ./expect-test.pl
Enter your input: bob 
You typed: bob
```

---

Or more simply, you can also try redirecting your input file into your perl script:

```
cat input.text 
bart

./expect-test.pl < input.text 
Enter your input: You typed: bart
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... its working now... 

And now i am getting PORT issue..

Comment: $  cat db_args.txt | perl /d06/oravis/db/tech_st/10.2.0/appsutil/clone/bin/adcfgclone.pl dbTier 

Target System Port Pool [0-99] : RC-00201: Error: Not a valid port pool number
======== 
$ cat db_args.txt 
apps
n
prodtest
/u01/oraprod
/usr/tmp
1
/u01/oraprod/db/apps_st/data
/u01/oraprod/db/tech_st/11.1.0
n
apps:0.0
30

Comment: I extended my test perl script to read in all of those values and it consumed them without issue. (1) I would examine the adcfgclone.pl script and see how they are accepting the input, especially at the pool number spot. (2) Make sure there is a newline after the port number and that each input is on it's own line (3) Try the expect route.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for the OP, but still relevant if someone else has the same question. 
Basically all the answers to these questions are in a file called the context file.
Once you set the Apps environment, the context file is in `${CONTEXT_FILE}`.
So by running:

```bsh
perl adcfgclone.pl appsTier "$CONTEXT_FILE"
```

you will only be asked for the Apps password.